# Operator Norm Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

so i am doing some exercise for my course of functional analysis. 
I need to show that, if $T: E \to E$ is a linear Operator and E an normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}$ and fulfills: $||T^n|| \to 0 \; (n\to \infty)$ then there are constants $C, \rho$ so that $$||T^n|| \le C \rho^n \; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}_0$$
I tried induction, estimating the expression and working with the Definition. Nothing worked out. Any help would be appreciated. Edit:
Forgot $\rho \in [0,1)$ sorry. C as You wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be such that $\|T^m\|\leq 1/2$ and $K$ be $\max_{i=1,2,\ldots,m}\|T^i\|$. Then we can write any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as $n=lm+i$ for some $i=1,2,\ldots,m$, and
$$
\|T^n\|=\|(T^m)^lT^i\|\leq\|T^m\|^l\|T^i\|\leq K(1/2)^l\leq 2K[(1/2)^{1/m}]^n.
$$

Comment: The key here is that $\|T^m\|=\rho<1$. But isn't it necessary that $\|T^n\|\leqslant \rho$ for $n\geqslant m$? It doesn't seem like you're actually using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|=0$ without that.

Comment: That is correct, one does not need the whole assumption.